# How to access miscall and new message state in android?

Tags: android

I wanna make an android app that runs in background and check if there is a miscall or new massage and if  it is true do something.How can I run my app in background (it does not close when I click back button) and how to access miscall and new message state I am an amateur in android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For not seen sms messages there is a column in content://sms that you can check in order to determine if a message has been seen.
Column name is "seen".

example of calling it and checking:

```
ContentResolver mContectResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        String[] mProjection = {
                "_id",
                "address",
                "person",
                "date",
                "body",
                "protocol",
                "seen"
        };

        Cursor cursor = mContectResolver.query(uri, mProjection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<cursor.getCount() ; i++){

                if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("seen")).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
//Message has not been seen
}
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
```

Comment: what should I define to it as context in line 1?

Comment: Context context = getApplicationContext(); It is just context that I get from Activity that is calling this method.